# How would i go about making a melee character that doesn't wear armor?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, armor, armor-class

I've been brainstorming an idea about a character that doesn't wear any armor at all using only their mobility to avoid getting hit.
I already know about Monk, Bracers of Armor, Mage armor and the like. I was hoping I could get some other ideas on how to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

[From X to Y](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1o91Z-s0R7Vf2Ujj1lFqGC5W--9JOyU0I6uC9XRIR5to/edit?usp=sharing), a Google Doc, includes all (as far as I know, as of its last revision) ways to gain alternate stats to various things. For AC:

Note: Per [this](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=385?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#19247) statement, you can only add an ability score to a statistic once, so if you already have Int/Wis/Cha to AC, other effects that tie that AC to that ability score would not increase it further. Note that this is based on the bonus type, so for example Canny Defense (an untyped bonus) would stack with Spell Shield (a shield bonus).

- Canny Defense* (Magus, ACF Kensai 1) Intelligence to Ac while unarmored addition to dex, max 1 pr class level
- Spell Shield (Magus 3; Magus Arcana) Spend 1 arcane point to gain Int as a Shield bonus to AC until end of next turn, doesn’t stack with shield
- Canny Defense* (Duelist 1) Intelligence to AC while unarmored addition to dex, max 1 pr class level
- Whispering Spirits (Investigator ACF Spiritualist 4) Use a commune with  spirits attempt to gain Wis as insight bonus to AC and Saves for 1 min.
- AC bonus (monk 1) add wisdom to AC and CMD when unarmored and unencumbered
- AC Bonus (Warpriest ACF Sacred Fist 1) add wisdom to AC and CMD when unarmored and unencumbered
- Smite (Warpriest ACF Champion of The Faith 4, 8, 12, 16, 20) Gain Cha to hit if target has chosen opposed alignment (Evil/Good/Chaos/Law), and Cha to Ac vs target.
- Smite evil (paladin 1,4,7,10,13,16,19, class feature) add charisma to hit/AC against evil smite target
- Bastion of Good (oathbound paladin ACF Sacred Shield 1) Cha to Ac against smite target, replaces smite evil
- Smite Good (Antipaladin 1,4,7,10,13,16,19) Charisma to hit and AC vs target good creatures
- Nature's Whisper (Oracle, nature mystery; revelation) use Charisma to AC and CMD **instead of** dex
- Sidestep Secret (oracle, lore mystery, revelation) Use Charisma to Ac and reflex saves **instead of** dex
- Prophetic Armor (Oracle 7, Lunar Revalation) Use Cha **instead of** dex for AC and reflex saves.
- Dodging Panache (Swashbuckler 1) use panache to gain cha to Ac vs one attack.
- Osyluth Guile (combat feat) add charisma to Ac against a single target, when using fighting defensively/total defense